# Binary Search and Generics

Tags: java, generics, recursion, computer-science

I am finishing up my project but I can not getting the answer that I need. This is what I have.

```
public class Question1<T extends Comparable>
{
private static Circle[] b = {};
private T key;

public Question1(Circle[] b, T key)
{
    Question1.b = b;
    this.key = key;
}


/**
 * @param aB the b to set
 */
public static void setB(Circle[] aB) {
    b = aB;
}
/**
 * @param key the key to set
 */
public void setKey(T key) {
    this.key = key;
}

/**
 *
 * @param b
 * @param low
 * @param high
 * @param x
 * @return 
 */
public String run(Circle[] b, int low, int high,int x)
{
    if(low > high)
    {
        return "This is not a Circle.";
    }
    else 
    {
        int mid = ((high + low)/2);
        if(key.compareTo(b[mid].radius) == 1)
        {
            return run(b,mid+1,high,x++);
        }
        else if( key.compareTo(b[mid].radius) == 0)
        {
            return run(b,low,mid-1,x++);
        }
        return "You wanted to find Circle: " + key + " It is in element: " + b[x];
    }
 }
}
```

Here is the circle object class with the compareTo() method

```
public class Circle implements Comparable<Circle>
{
  public double radius;
  public Circle() {
  }

public Circle(double r)
{
    this.radius = r;
}
public void setRadius(double radius)
{
    this.radius = radius;
}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return " " + radius;
}
/**
 *
 * @param t
 * @return
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(Circle t)
{
    if(this.radius < t.radius)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(this.radius > t.radius)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 2;
}
}
```

Here is my start method

```
public class Start 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Circle[] b = {new Circle(1),new Circle(2),new Circle(3),new Circle(4),new Circle(5),new Circle(6)};
    double key = 4;
    Question1 qu = new Question1(b,key);

    System.out.println(qu.run(b, 0, b.length,0));
}
}
```

The problem is when I start comparing the radii. lets say I create an array of circles

```
Circle[] b = {new Circle(1),new Circle(2),new Circle(3),new Circle(4),new Circle(5),new Circle(6)};
```

I want to find a circle with radii of 4. but my code doesn't find it and goes to "this is not a circle" what I think it is that I have not coded the compareTo method correctly. If not what can I do to correct what is happening?

Comment: Where do you initially call run from? Could it be that low > high initially? It would be good to step through with a debugger if you haven't so that you can see the various states of variables as you call run.

Comment: That's what I have been doing, I just don't understand. This is my call

run(b, 0, b.length,0)

Comment: You haven’t shown us how you instantiate your `Question1<>` class, or how you call the `run` method with your array of circles, and search data.  There is much that is wrong with your code, but we can’t even begin to help without seeing your full attempt.

Comment: i'll edit my post.

Comment: The `Comparable.compareTo` method does not/should not return 0, 1 or 2 for greater than, smaller than and equals, like you seem to assume. It should return < 0 for smaller than, 0 for equals and > 1 for greater than. Look at the Javadoc. And you're not using the compareTo method in your circle class, but the compareTo method in `java.lang.Double` in your `run` method. And there is so much else wrong with your code (`static` field `b`, which isn't even used, since you use a passed in parameter `b` in your `run` method - and why is it called `run` and not `search`?, etc.)

Comment: I'm in the process of making it look better.

Comment: You are not using generics properly.  `Question1 qu = ...` lacks the `<...>` template argument after the class name.  And if you are always comparing to a circle’s radius, there isn’t much point to specifying anything other than `Double` as the template argument... in which case there is nothing remotely generic about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a binary search (using the radius of the circle), and had a few problems.

1. Circle compareTo:

Use the Double compare method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Circle t) {
    return Double.compare(this.radius, t.radius);
}
```

2. Run method

Wrong use of compare; replace with

```
public String run(Circle[] b, int low, int high, int x) {
    if (low > high || ((low == high) && high >= b.length)) {
        return "This Circle is not found.";
    } else {
        int mid = ((high + low) / 2);
        if (key.compareTo(b[mid].radius) == 0)
            return "You wanted to find Circle: " + key + " It is in element: " + mid;
        if (key.compareTo(b[mid].radius) > 0) {
            return run(b, mid + 1, high, x++);
        } else {
            return run(b, low, mid - 1, x++);
        }
    }
}
```

With these changes, the search finds all of the circles in your test array, and works for cases where the radius is less than the lowest, or higher than the highest.

I am not sure what you are trying to do with variable `x`?  Perhaps count how many iterations it takes to find the key?  But you don't use it.

Comment: The x gives me the place of where the element is, this is the answer thank you for showing me and I can see why my code didn't work.